# How many Reactions can a player get per round?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, reactions

There's been some discussion lately around one of my tables about Reactions. Some are of the opinion that you only get 1 Reaction per round. Others say this is not necessarily true.

According to the Player's Handbook *(Combat > Your Turn > Reactions)*:

> When you take a reaction, you can’t take another one until the start of your next turn. If the reaction interrupts another creature’s turn, that creature can continue its turn right after the reaction.

This wording implies that a character who is not first in the Initiative order could get 2 Reactions in the first round of combat. To do this, they would use a reaction before their turn, and then again at some point in the round after their turn has started.

That being said, I had thought that I had read somewhere that you only got one Reaction per round of combat, but I can't seem to find it. Obviously, whatever the DM rules is what it is, but I'm curious about what RAW has to say on this topic.

**How many Reactions can a player get per round?**

Comment: Hi aaron9eee.  I am closing your question as a duplicate.  That's ok! because it will now serve as an additional search hit for people with similar questions.  Please read the linked question and its answers, especially [this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/150749/23547) one.  Hopefully it answers your question, but if it doesn't, feel free to edit your question to explain what you are still confused about so that we can reopen your question and answer it.

Comment: @Kirt Depending on how you look at it they aren't the same question. Strictly speaking, if a character was changed into a maralith they could get a reaction in on every single turn. I'm not sure if that is exactly what the question is about though.

Comment: @AllanMills The maralith sounds like its own question - but I would be happy to re-open it if the OP has not been answered.